# How to release ArrayList From Memory In Java With Struts2

Tags: java, arraylist

I have class where i have around 10 ArrayList and i newbie to Garbage Collection I learned releasing Objects from memory can be done in three way...
    Using Anonymous object or making it null.....but in my action after getting i cant make it null nothing shows up in jsp page... here is my code...

```
class myAction extends ActionSupport{
private ArrayList<Object> ShopList1=new  ArrayList<Object>();
private ArrayList<Object> ShopList2=new  ArrayList<Object>();
private ArrayList<Object> ShopList3=new  ArrayList<Object>();
private ArrayList<Object> ShopList4=new  ArrayList<Object>();
private ArrayList<Object> ShopList5=new  ArrayList<Object>();
public execute{

ShopList1.put("Adding 20 Object");
ShopList2.put("Adding 20 Object");
ShopList3.put("Adding 20 Object");
ShopList4.put("Adding 20 Object");

setShopList1(ShopList1);
setShopList2(ShopList2);
setShopList3(ShopList3);
setShopList4(ShopList4);
setShopList5(ShopList5);
//If i make All arrayList Null the result does not show up in JSP...
return SUCCESS;
}

public ArrayList<Object> getShopList1() {
            return ShopList1;
        }
        public void setShopList1(ArrayList<Object> shopList1) {
            ShopList1 = shopList1;
        }
        public ArrayList<Object> getShopList2() {
            return ShopList2;
        }
        public void setShopList2(ArrayList<Object> shopList2) {
            ShopList2 = shopList2;
        }
        public ArrayList<Object> getShopList3() {
            return ShopList3;
        }
        public void setShopList3(ArrayList<Object> shopList3) {
            ShopList3 = shopList3;
        }
        public ArrayList<Object> getShopList4() {
            return ShopList4;
        }
        public void setShopList4(ArrayList<Object> shopList4) {
            ShopList4 = shopList4;
        }
        public ArrayList<Object> getShopList5() {
            return ShopList5;
        }
        public void setShopList5(ArrayList<Object> shopList5) {
            ShopList5 = shopList5;
        }

}
```

So my Question is when do i release the arrayList or does JVM do it for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ArrayList.remove(object)** if you wants to remove objects from the List Not from the Memory.

You can not force Garbage collector to garbage from heap. Normally it automatically eligible as garbage collector when it has no reference